# How to check if there is a color code in a file and transform it into a close value?

Tags: python, colors, hex

I am currently trying to study Python as an autodidact (self-taught person) and I am facing a problem that is causing me a lot of trouble.
Here's what I've been trying to do for a few weeks.

I am trying to create a small script in python that can detect if there is a color code (`#FC0000`) in a file, to automatically convert it to decimal values (`252,0,0`) and round the `252` to the nearest value in multiples of `5`. i.e.
`252`→`250`, `167`→`170`, etc.

I would like some help learning or paying to get this script so I can study it. This exercise is part of a training that I follow, and I'm stuck.

Comment: you can convert hex to int with `int('FC',16),int('00',16),...` you can find all the colors by regex `re.findall("#[A-Za-z0-9]",a_bunch_of_text)` .... you can easily get slices of a string `rgb_strings = color_string[1:3],color_string[3:5],color_string[5:7]` put it all together and you have your answer ...

Comment: Do you know how to get color codes from the file or is your question primarily about transforming the values read? It's usually best to limit your questions to one topic here.

Answer (score 0):

I really not understand what you want, but if you wanna convert hex color to rgb you can do like this:

```
hex = input('Enter HEX value: ').lstrip('#')
print('RGB value =', tuple(int(hex[i:i+2], 16) for i in (0, 2, 4)))
```

and you can Rounds a number with call round(your number, -1)

Comment: Seems like this would be relatively easily to extend to produce values that were multiples of 5…

Comment: idk, but i use this and its work for me

Comment: Never said it didn't work — merely that it looks like it could *also* do the find the nearest multiple of 5 logic the OP wanted.

Comment: oh yeah bro, you right

Answer (score 0):

There are several different ways this could be done. The code below uses built-ins to simplify implementing certain aspects of the transformation. It first uses the `int` class initializer to convert the hexadecimal portion of the color value into an integer numerical value. Then it uses the `divmod()` function to extract successive "digits" of the equivalent base-256 representation of each digit. Lastly it uses the `round()` function to convert the value of each digit to the closest value that's a multiple of 5.

Note that it converts 167 → 165, because it's closer to it than the 170 you have in your question.

```
def transform_color_code(hex_color):
    """ Convert color in hex notation to RGB triplet. """
    n = int(hex_color[1:], 16)
    if n == 0:
        return (0, 0, 0)
    arr = []
    while n:
        n, rem = divmod(n, 256)
        rem = 5 * round(rem/5)  # Round to nearest multiple of 5.
        arr.append(rem)
    return tuple(reversed(arr))


print(transform_color_code('#FCA700'))  # -> (250, 165, 0)
```